# OpenStack networking behind ISP router

Tags: networking, openstack

I am currently looking into OpenStack. To test it, I installed DevStack on my Intel NUC running on Debian 11 (needed to add the backport repositories to resolve the openvswitch errors from the script).

How do I assign adresses from my local network? Otherwise how can I tell my NUC to route the OpenStack internal network? (I can enter subnets and their gateways in my isps router)

```
Local Subnet (provided by ISP router): 192.168.178.0/24
ISP Router IP: 192.168.178.1
DevStack NUC IP: 192.168.178.240
```

Looking into Horizon Dashboard -> Admin -> Networks I can only see the networks in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66bIa.png).

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: IIUC you're looking for [provider networks](https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/launch-instance-networks-provider.html). You would add a network and subnet to openstack which contain a pool from your local network so you could use it within openstack.

Comment: Thank you for that! That helped me. It is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer for posterity:
You're looking for [provider networks](https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/launch-instance-networks-provider.html). You would add a network and subnet to openstack which contain a pool from your local network so you could use it within openstack.